GetGenericArguments Recursively on inherited class type in C#?
In C# I have
class Gen1<T1, T2> {}
class Gen2<T2>: Gen1<MyObject, T2> {}
class Ins: Gen2<MyInterface> {}

var ins = new Ins();
Type insType = ins.GetType();

How can I get MyObject and MyInterface from insType (with correct order?)
I tried:
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

do
{
    types.AddRange(checkType.GetGenericArguments());
    if(checkType.IsGenericType)
    {
        Type genType = checkType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

        types.AddRange(genType.GetGenericArguments());
    }
    checkType = checkType.BaseType;
} while (checkType != null);

This gives MyInterface and T2. It did find the Gen2<T2> type, but I have no idea how to get that MyObject when Gen2 inherent from Gen1, and how to make the order correct too.

It's not entirely clear what you want.  Are you asking how to get the generic arguments for the base type Gen1<T1, T2> using reflection from the type Ins?  Or are you asking for something more general?  If you require something more general, can you please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements?  Thanks!

What you want are the generic arguments to the base-of-base type Gen1<T1, T2>.  To get those, it will be convenient to introduce the following extension method:
public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        yield return type;
        type = type.BaseType!;
    }
}

And now you will be able to do:
var types = insType.BaseTypesAndSelf()
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Gen1<,>))
    .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments())
    .FirstOrDefault();

Resulting in [MyObject,MyInterface].
Or if you want the generic arguments to the topmost generic base type whatever it is, you could introduce the following additional extension method:
// Returns the generic arguments of the topmost base type which is generic, or an empty array if there is none.
public static Type [] GetTopmostBaseTypeGenericArguments(this Type type) =>
    type.BaseTypesAndSelf()
        .Where(t => t.IsGenericType)
        .Reverse()
        .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments())
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? Array.Empty<Type>();

And then do
var types = insType.GetTopmostBaseTypeGenericArguments();

Or if you have e.g.
class MyKeyObjectDictionary<TKey> : Dictionary<TKey, MyObject> where TKey : notnull;
class MyStringObjectDictionary : MyKeyObjectDictionary<string>;

Then
var types = typeof(MyStringObjectDictionary).GetTopmostBaseTypeGenericArguments(); 

will return [System.String,MyObject].
Demo here.

Thanks so much for this solution! This works very well on your demo and the code piece in my question. I'm using it on Unity (game engine) and it does not work there, so I must miss (or mislead) something... Please give me some time to figure out... Your answer is really helpful and thanks for your time!

Edit: after some digging around, it looks like some weird implement on Unity itself. When I run the code in C#, it works perfect. But when in Unity where it only gives fieldInfo.FieldType to use, that type's .BaseType will go: Ins -> Gen2[MyInterface] -> System.Object, so somehow Unity just skip the middle Gen1... I believe it's the issue from Unity not C#. Thanks for the detailed help!
